# IE6 ignoring active link CSS style

Tags: html, css

The CSS active link style is being correctly applied in IE7, FF, and Safari but is not applied IE6.

```
.side_nav a.active 
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#9F1F63;
}
```

Interestingly the background color (background-color:#9F1F63;) is being applied in IE6 but not the font color (color:#FFFFFF;)

Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can fix it appreciated.

The complete styling for the nav below:

```
.side_nav 
{
    text-align : left;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.side_nav ul 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position:inside;
    margin-left:0px;
}
.side_nav li 
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type:none;   
}
.side_nav a, .side_nav a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color : #9F1F63;
    font-weight : bold;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;     
}
.side_nav a:hover 
{
    color:#B26D7F;
}
.side_nav a.active 
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#9F1F63;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks but the suggestions haven't helped. When I change to a:active the active effect does not work in any browser. I think this might be due to how I have applied the style in the HTML.

```
    <div class="side_nav">
        <a class="active" href="Page1.aspx">Page1</a><br />
        <a href="Page2.aspx">Page2</a><br />
        <a href="Page3.aspx">Page3</a><br />
    </div>
```

Comment: After seeing your edit, I'd be inclined to think it's a problem with the class name 'active' if nothing below has helped. I don't have IE6 on this machine to verify but I've seen it choke on weirder issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried copying your code, and the format did work.
Your problem is you see the link as visited - you have both formatting of the visited and active (so you have the purple background and the purple text).
You should override the color for visited links with the active class:

```
.side_nav a.active, .side_nav a.active:visited
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #9F1F63;
}
```

Comment: Thanx Kobi! It was the visited link. Working consistently in IE6 now.

Answer (score 5):

In IE6, it matters which order you specify the anchor links. You should specify them in this order to achieve the intended result: first a:link, then a:visited, a:hover and a:active.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the order. This did not help though. See edit above.

Answer (score 4):

Your CSS has a period where there should be a colon, in `.side_nav a.active` (should be `.side_nav a:active`

With this fixed, it works for me in IE6.

Comment: When I use a:active none of the active effects apply in any browser. With a.active both the effects apply in all browsers I have tested except IE6.

Comment: Thanks for testing it in IE6. I wonder whether we have an older version here in our locked down environment.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a more specific selector to `.side_nav a.active` such as `div .side_nav a.active` where `div` is the parent element.

The color is probably being overwritten from the `.side_nav a` rule.

Also, you may have a typo - are trying to use the :active selector?

Comment: See his HTML example.  It's a class name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `!important`. Like this:

```
.side_nav a.active
{
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #9F1F63;
}
```

Comment: If `!important` solves the problem then, 19 times in 20 (if not more) you should be writing more specific selectors instead. `!important` is a clumsy weapon.